# Fizzbuzz but without if

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

Code first, elaboration later:

```
// Fizzbuzz: 1..100, %3->fizz, %5->buzz, %15->fizzbuzz
// noif: do not use if/switch statements or ternary expressions
// LIMIT must be a power of 10
// WIDTH must be equal to log10(LIMIT)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIMIT 100
#define WIDTH 2

char *
itoa(int n)
{
    static char out[WIDTH + 1];

    for(char *outp = out + WIDTH - 1; outp >= out; --outp, n /= 10)
        *outp = '0' + n % 10;

    return out;
}

void
fizzbuzz(int n)
{
    static char *FBSTR[4] = {"", "Fizz", "Buzz"};

    FBSTR[3] = itoa(n);
    fputs(FBSTR[1 * (n%3 == 0)], stdout);
    fputs(FBSTR[2 * (n%5 == 0)], stdout);
    fputs(FBSTR[3 * (n%3 > 0 && n%5 > 0)], stdout);
    putchar('\n');
}

int
main(void)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= LIMIT; ++i)
        fizzbuzz(i);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been reading a little bit about the anti-if campaign, and decided to try my hand at a challenge: Fizzbuzz but without if statements.

Because I'm not trying to be cheap, that also means no switch statements,

```
switch(n % 3){
    case 0: fputs("fizz", stdout); break;
}
```

no ternary expressions,

```
fputs((n % 3 == 0) ? ("fizz") : (""), stdout);
```

and no contrived while loops.

```
int lock = 0;

while(lock++ == 0 && n % 3 == 0)
    fputs("fizz", stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *
itoa(int n)
{
    static char out[WIDTH + 1];

    for(char *outp = out + WIDTH - 1; outp >= out; --outp, n /= 10)
        *outp = '0' + n % 10;
```

Nice bounds-check (`outp >= out`). This ensures that you don't overrun your buffer when given a very large integer. However, since `out-1` is not a valid pointer value, `outp >= out` is an *incorrect* bounds-check for the same reason that

```
int decr(int x) {
    int y = x - 1;
    if (y > x) return 0;  // oops, overflow happened
    return y;
}
```

is an *incorrect* overflow-check.

Your bounds-check code also has another similarity to the above overflow-check code: When overflow happens, you return an *in-range value* that the caller might reasonably confuse for a valid result of the function. When `itoa(x)` returns `"42"`, does it mean that `x` was `42`, or does it mean that `x` was `1042` and overflow happened? It would be much better to say, if overflow happens, we return `NULL`.

Of course you'll have to express that "if" without `if`. ;)

---

`itoa` returns `char*`, but you don't expect the caller to modify the pointed-to chars, so you should declare it as returning a pointer to non-modifiable chars: `const char*`. [Const is a contract.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/)

Similarly, `static char *FBSTR[4]` should be `static const char *FBSTR[4]`.

---

```
static const char *FBSTR[4] = {"", "Fizz", "Buzz", NULL};
```

would be much clearer to the human reader; it shows that you didn't miscount the number of array elements. In fact, you might even write

```
static const char *FBSTR[] = {"", "Fizz", "Buzz", NULL};
```

although the downside of that is that the number of indices is actually *really important* to your algorithm, so I can see a valid argument for keeping the `4` in this case.

---

```
fputs(FBSTR[1 * (n%3 == 0)], stdout);
fputs(FBSTR[2 * (n%5 == 0)], stdout);
fputs(FBSTR[3 * (n%3 > 0 && n%5 > 0)], stdout);
putchar('\n');
```

I did puzzle this out, but printing all those empty strings feels like a strange way to go about it. Why not simply

```
int idx = 1*(n%3 == 0)
        + 2*(n%5 == 0)
        + 3*(n%3 != 0 && n%5 != 0);
fputs(FBSTR[idx], stdout);
putchar('\n');
```

In which case you can combine the `fputs` and `putchar` into

```
puts(FBSTR[idx]);
```

---

If you think it would be easier to understand, you could even rewrite the index computation using bitwise operations:

```
const char *FBSTR[] = {itoa(n), "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz"};
int idx = (n%3 == 0) + 2*(n%5 == 0);
puts(FBSTR[idx]);
```

---

To avoid reinventing the wheel, you could replace `itoa(n)` with `snprintf(somelocalbuffer, sizeof somelocalbuffer, "%d", n)`. However, for this toy example, `itoa` does have a more ergonomic interface; and reinventing the wheel isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Lots of good advice, some I'd even thought about myself before posting (ambiguous itoa `42`/`...42`, FBSTR should explicitly declare its fourth element, use of `char const*` instead of `char*`, `ptr - ... - 1` could backfire if `...` ever happens to be `0`). I haven't been to CR in a while--should I edit my question to integrate your advice, or is that against the spirit of CR?

Comment: I will say that I'm a bit confused by the third-to-last piece of advice, which seems to be telling me to add the three indices together, which, to my understanding, would cause my program to output itoa's buffer rather than "FizzBuzz" when `n % 15 == 0` is true.